# Experiencing a strange tile rendering bug in Unity's Scene view

Tags: unity-game-engine, tile

This issue only affects the Scene view, and it is not present in the Game view or when it is running.

Basically my map looks like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0cjA.png

Zoomed Out
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDfB5.png

As you can see there are horizontal lines everywhere. The grid is turned off. They are mostly blue because underneath the grass tile on the sheet is the water tile. You can see under the left of the rock there is a yellowish line, this is because there is a sandy tile below it. The individual images from the Sprite editor look fine. No lines in them. As mentioned, this is only present in the scene view and doesn't affect the game so its not major. I would really like to see if this is possible to fix though as it is quite a pain to look at and design maps with. This issue is present on my PC, and both laptops so I don't think it's hardware related.

Tile palette images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmno3.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4csen.png

I've tried adding them to an Atlas, checked for Point (no filter) and no compression. I'm at a loss. No one seems to know how to fix the issue and all my googling points me to bleed or tears in the actual game which is not the issue I am having.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I will provide any additional information that is needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, looking at https://i.imgur.com/huNDlHy.png, Id have said there was a 1 pixel line at the top of the green grass that is missing

Comment: At first I was thinking they got sliced wrong in the sprite editor too but they look correct in the individual tile images. The tiles are only 16x16 px so the line I'm seeing is like 1/16th or smaller of a pixel. I even attempted different tilesets and they all do the same thing.  
https://i.imgur.com/70yfPUh.png

Im just at a loss and no one seems to have an answer haha.   
I may just have to give up and used Tiled even if I lose some functionality. Or just suck it up and deal with it as the bug isn't present in the actual game, just the scene view.

Comment: does it look wrong at run time?

Answer (score 1):

So after a few days of frustration and help from the Unity discord, I finally found an answer.

It turns out you want to disable Pixel Snap in your Shader component on your tilemap object. As soon as I did that all the lines in Scene View were gone.

Setting to change: [image]